# Struts2 multiple select box pre-selecting current options

Tags: java, struts2

I have created a form & action in struts2 for editing a User record, a User may have one or more Roles and I have a form were a multiple select box is used to select the roles for a given user. The select box contents is read from the database and I want the select box to pre-select the users current options when loading the form, using examples found online I have the following.

In my action class

```
public List<Role> getRoles()
{
    return roles;
}


public void setRoles( List<Role> roles )
{
    this.roles = roles;
}


public List<Role> getAvailableRoles()
{
    return availableRoles;
}
```

In my JSP

```
<s:select list="availableRoles" listKey="id" listValue="name" name="roles" label="Roles" multiple="true" />
```

The multiple select box is created fine however no items are selected to begin with and I am a bit confused as every example I have found does just this.

I did try changing the select box to just this:

```
<s:select list="availableRoles" name="roles" label="Roles" multiple="true" />
```

This way does successfully pre-select the options however then the drop down is populated with whatever is returned from the toString() method on my Role class not specifically the getId() and getName() methods which is what I want. Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the struts2 source code it seems my answer was fairly obvious. I need to implement the .equals() method on my Role class for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that `getRoles()` and `setRoles()` needs to be a `List<String>` not `List<Roles>`. This is because HTML `select` use strings for it's keys. Change the type to `List<String>` and initialise the roles variable with the Id's of the roles for the user's current options. This is because you have `listkey=id`. You will need `multiple=true` as well.

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem because I want the listKey and listValue to be different.

Comment: My answer allows you to use different values for listkey and listvalue. However getRoles() and setRoles() needs to be of the same type as your listkey.